# Automatic schema generation from code

Tags: asp.net, configuration, schema, intellisense

For configuring my ASP.Net Application I'm using Custom Configuration Sections in my web.config. But I would like to get IntelliSense support for my own-build configuration sections. I figured that it is possible to create a XSD Schema Definition and include that in the web.config. But is there a less painful way of getting that schema?

With [Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com/) I found a tool offering a GUI for creating my configuration section and generating the schema. But I like coding and I don't want to learn how to deal with another GUI.

So, is there a possibility of automatically generating the schema for my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [this tool](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/System_Xml_Schema/BuildSchema/BuildXMLSchema.aspx) to generate generic schema from xml; See if it helps in your case.